# Initiating a Struct with 1D and 2D array components in c

Tags: c, arrays, struct, segmentation-fault, coredump

I have been having some trouble recently with creating a structure that is made from 1D and 2D arrays. The size of the arrays are big and I only want to initiate the struct. This is what I have so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct frame{
int time[8000];
int number[8000];
int position[8000][480];
int xcoordinates[8000][480];
int ycoordinates[8000][480];};

int main(int argc, char **argv){
frame testing;
return 0;}
```

When I run this code, I get a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". What would be a possible solution to this problem?

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: size of `frame` is 44MB on 32bit system. Too large for the stack. use malloc.

Comment: Agreed, too large for typically allowed stack sizes. In case you don't like `malloc()`, make the variable global or static

Comment: what about `struct frame testing;`?

Comment: @user3078414 Perhaps OP is using C++ as C.

Comment: thanks, ran few tests - agree on stack size issue and a question duplicate.